# Object is possibly 'undefined' when init a variable Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

I have a component in my app like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-intent',
  templateUrl: './payment-intent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-intent.component.css']
})
export class PaymentIntentComponent implements OnInit {

  static = false;
  @ViewChild(StripeCardComponent, this.static) card: StripeCardComponent;
```

But, when i try to compile the app, i get

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'
```

The error is in the variable `static = false` that is causing that `@ViewChild(StripeCardComponent, this.static) card` is receiving the variable as possible `undefined`, but as you can see the variable is not `undefined`, the variable is a boolean initializated in `false`..

What can i do to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try defining it as `static: boolean = false;`.  But the problem might be that `static` is a reserved word, so you might want to rename your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the Angular's [Static Query Migration](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration) where it shows that the `@ViewChild` 2nd parameter is `{ static: boolean }` type, so you should edit yours to:

```
@ViewChild(StripeCardComponent, { static: this.static }) card: StripeCardComponent;
```

or much better to assign it directly, since this condition will apply upon initialization:

```
@ViewChild(StripeCardComponent, { static: false }) card: StripeCardComponent;
```

Answer (score 3):

@ViewChild, in this case, is a decorator. To understand the problem, you need to understand how decorators work and how they apply to methods.

Original code:

```
function decorator(value?:any) {
  return function <T>(target: unknown, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>): void {
    console.log('value:', value);
  };
}

class Bar {
    @decorator(this)
    public foo():void {}
}
```

Compiled code:

```
// __decorate and __metadata declarations skipped

function decorator(value) {
  return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    console.log('value:', value);
  };
}

class Bar {
  foo() { }
}

__decorate([
  decorator(this),
  __metadata("design:type", Function),
  __metadata("design:paramtypes", []),
  __metadata("design:returntype", void 0)
], Bar.prototype, "foo", null);
```

After compiling this code, you can see that the decorators modify the prototype class, not its instance. Thus, **"this"** in the argument "this.static" you pass to the decorator **points to no context**, and therefore its value is undefined.

Comment: Very well explained. I think this this explanation should be provided by TypeScript in the documentation, or concisely summarized in the error message directly.